# Create ZIP of files based on date, Linux

Tags: linux, bash, zip

I am creating a zip file of some files (image files), but need to limit it such that only the latest files are added to the zip file. I need files that are more than 2 days old. Exact time is not relevant.

This is what I have been doing, but how do I limit it based on date? This is Linux and is run from a batch .sh file.

```
zip -r /destination_path/media_backup.zip /from_path/media
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you want the latest files or the files that are older than 2 days? Either way you can use the same basic command:

```
zip -r /destination_path/media_backup.zip $(find /from_path/media -type f -mtime +2)
```

You just need to adjust the `mtime` option according to your requirements. `+X` means "last modified more than X days ago", `-X` would be "last modified less than X days ago". If you need more resolution, you could use `-mmin` instead, which checks against minutes rather than days.

Comment: One problem I had using this method was when some of the files I wanted to zip up contained a space in their name. The zip process was treating them as separate files, and this failing. Using the method bhargav Modi suggested at the end solved this for me.

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
zip -rtt 2014-12-13 /destination_path/media_backup.zip /from_path/media
```

You can find more options using the zip man page.

```
-tt Do not operate on files modified after or at the specified date
```

Comment: If you need to operate only on files modified after the specified date, just use -t instead of -tt

Answer (score 2):

this should work, M not sure and I had not tried.

```
find / -mtime +2 -ls > input.txt
cat input.txt | zip myzipfile.zip -@
```

Comment: This is close, but you should remove "-ls" from your find operation to make it work right, and only search for file types:   find . -type f -mtime +2 > input.txt

Comment: Please don't leave untested command line answers. The risk of causing chaos is high.